# Creating Submodels in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have a rails association question. I am building an equipment management app and I am having trouble determining the design of the model associations.

So a user can create an Asset which has :make, :model, :year, :location, and other common attributes including :asset_type. The asset type could be a number of different types of equipment such as dozer, bus, engine, excavator, tender, etc.

I had considered using STI but the asset types do not share the same attributes. What I am leaning towards is making a separate model for each asset type that would belong_to :asset and then accept_nested_params for each asset type in the Asset model so that I can create them in the same form using javascript to show an asset_type partial once the user chooses :asset_type from a select field. Then to access it I would need to do something like:

```
def show
  @asset = Asset.find(params[:id)
  @asset_type = @asset.asset_type.classify.constantize.find(params[@asset.id])
end
```

This feels wrong to me. It seems to me that this would be very common situation and maybe I am just missing something very obvious.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I would create different models if some of the fields would stay empty for some of the type of assets. Otherwise one model will suffice.

Comment: I think you are on the right path. Make each asset type its own model (i.e. with its own corresponding database table), and then use `belongs_to :asset_type, polymorphic: true`. The polymorphic association will take care of loading for you so you don't have to do classify, constantize, etc. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Polymorphic+Associations

Comment: Thanks Matt I'll look into using polymorphic association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the following code would work because `constantize` doesn't actually take any arguments ([source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize)).

```
  @asset_type = @asset.asset_type.classify.constantize(find[@asset.id])
```

If you're defining `@asset.asset_type` from user input, I wouldn't advise using `classify.constantize` because there's vulnerability to code injection.

But if `asset_type` is limited to a few pre-defined values and you have corresponding classes for each `asset_type`, it should be a workable approach

```
# in models/asset.rb   
   validates :asset_type, :inclusion=> { :in => ["bulldozer", "firetruck"] }
   def asset_type_object
     asset_type.classify.constantize.find_by(asset_id: id)
   end

# assuming Bulldozer and Firetruck classes are also defined

# in the controller
  @asset_type = @asset.asset_type_object
```

Note that I've also replaced your `.constantize(find[@asset.id])` with `.constantize.find_by(asset_id: id)`. This is because it doesn't make sense to find a `AssetType` which has the same primary key as an `Asset`. You should use foreign keys for associations.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Max. And thanks for pointing out the typo.  `.constantize(find[@asset.id])` was just a syntax error and I like that you put it in a method.

Comment: Sure. One other thing to remember is that instance variables defined in the controller won't be available in the Model. I just fixed that in my answer.